# MyTouch 4g MMS over Home Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, mms

Why can't I receive or send MMS on my My Touch 4g through my home Wi-Fi? I have bad coverage at home so I have to use my Wi-Fi connection. I'm sure my settings are right - I have it set to T-Mobile Data. Does it have to be set at MMS? It works fine when I'm away from home on the 4g network.

Answer (score 1):

MMS messages can only be received by your carrier's internet service (3g,4g,etc.). Sadly the capabilities to do this over wi-fi are not available yet, hopefully they're working on a fix for this!